# "could not found goal" error when using Maven to run main class in JPA

Tags: jpa, maven-3

I am learning JPA, I created a project to test the simplest function that: persist object to derby database,
this is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLNSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>java</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <name>AJP</name>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0</version>
      </dependency>    
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
          <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
          <version>10.6.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
          <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
          <version>10.6.1.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>      
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>                
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>              
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>

            <executions>
              <execution>               
                <goals>                 
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                  <goal></goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <executable>maven</executable>
              <!-- optional -->
              <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
              <arguments>
                <argument>-X</argument>
                <argument>myproject:dist</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I start derby and then use this command: `mvn exec -Dexec.mainCLass="newmain"` 
(newmain is my main class)

I recieve weird error that: `could not found goal ''` in `plugin org.codehause.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 among avaiable goals exec`

Thanks for your help, guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to run the exec plugin you must call a goal and not the lifecycle. If you call

```
mvn exec  ...
```

this is a lifecycle which does not exist. To run you have to give this:

```
mvn exec:exec ...
```

which represents a goal in [maven-exec-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html).